# Conditionally Splitting a String in Python

Tags: python, split

I have a string that looks like this:

```
Increase (decrease)      1,334      (     2,921)     2,797
```

I'd like to split the string to look like this:

```
['Increase (decrease)', '1,334', '(2,921)', '2,797']
```

I've tried:

```
item=re.split(r'\s{3,}', strg)
```

But clearly this yields:

```
['Increase (decrease)', '1,334', '(', '2,921)', '2,797']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But why do you want to split like this? What's the rule?  I have no idea what the result should be for example for 'abc (123) (a a)'. Just explain the rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove all spaces after an opening parenthesis and then split:

```
>>> re.split(r'\s{3,}', re.sub(r"(?<=\()\s+", "", s))
['Increase (decrease)', '1,334', '(2,921)', '2,797']
```

Note that `(?<=\()` is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the spaces between parenthesis and then split:

```
>>> re.split(r'\s{3,}',re.sub(r'(?<=\()\s+','',s))
['Increase (decrease)', '1,334', '(2,921)', '2,797']
```